# Tred Chart Using Highcharts Chart

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

in an html page I'm trying to use Highcharts Chart to build a chart but the sometimes data label disappear behind the graph (e.g. image below)

[image]

This is my js code that build the graph:

```
var chartBehaviour = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart : {
                    renderTo : 'driving-behaviour-chart',
                    type : 'column'
                },
                xAxis : {
                    categories : labelXAxis,
                    lineColor : "#f5f5f5",
                    tickLength : 0,
                    labels : {
                        y: 40,
                        style : {
                            'color' : '#666666',
                            fontSize : '14px',
                            fontFamily : '\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis : {
                    title : {
                        enabled : false
                    },
                    gridLineColor : "#f5f5f5",
                    tickInterval : 10,
                    labels : {
                        style : {
                            'color' : '#666666',
                            fontSize : '12px',
                            fontFamily : '\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits : {
                    enabled : false
                },
                title : false,
                tooltip : false,
                legend : false,
                plotOptions : {
                    series : {
                        borderWidth : 0,
                        pointWidth : 22
                    },
                    column : {
                        animation : false,
                        pointPadding : 0.23,
                        dataLabels : {
                            enabled : true,
                            align : 'left',
                            enabled : true,
                            rotation : 0,
                            verticalAlign : "top",
                            x : -1,
                            y : -30,
                            style : {
                                "color" : "#68a1b1",
                                fontFamily : '\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif',
                                fontSize : "14px"
                            }
                        },
                        states : {
                            hover : {
                                enabled : false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series : [{
                        data : trends.drivingBehaviour,

                        color : "#68a1b1",
                        borderRadiusTopLeft : 5,
                        borderRadiusTopRight : 5,
                        borderRadiusBottomRight : 5,
                        borderRadiusBottomLeft : 5
                    }
                ]
            });
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this graph? Thank you.

Comment: The column label is not "behind" the chart. It is the same color as your column. Try using different colors for data column and label or different label styles.

Comment: ^ In addition to that, try seetting `crop` to `false`, and `overflow` to `'none'` in your `dataLabels` settings. Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow  It is pushing the label down, because it is determining that there is not enough space inside the plot area to render the label above the bar

Comment: Thank you jlbriggs, seems that I need Crop and overflow now work like a charm :)